# GetReferencedAssemblies doesn't return all assemblies

Tags: .net, reflection

I have the following code inside a Form, and am attempting to find a way to load a project assembly referenced by the form called `DataObjects`.  Using the following code, I only get six assemblies listed.  Looking at the references for the project the form is in, there are thirteen assembly references.  What is wrong here?

```
private void ListReferencedAssemblies()
{
    var assemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        referencesListBox.Items.Add(assembly.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Could you please check the assembly's manifest to see what is referenced here?

C# compiler tends to remove referenced assemblies from the manifest if they are not used. Therefore if you don't refer to any type from assembly B or refer only to constants from assembly B (that are inlined by complier) then you will not have this references.

Comment: Is there any way to force the 'unused' assembly to be loaded?

Comment: Assembly.Load() if you know the place to load in current domain or write some dummy code to refer to types from 'unused' assemblies.

Comment: I believe you (I am running in to the same issue at the moment), but do you happen to have a source?

Comment: @AndreyTaptunov: "or write some dummy code" - unfortunately, that is only possible if the assembly contains any public types.

Answer (score 14):

The compiler will not include assembly references in the output assembly that are not actually used in code.

Only assemblies that are used from code will be referenced in the output assembly.

Comment: "that are not actually used in code" - I think this should be written differently. When I something I call relies on the presence of types discovered via reflection (in my case, via MEF), those types *are* used. That is, they would be used, if the compiler had not removed the reference and thereby made my application crash.

Comment: That is really painful if the reference is "used" via reflection for example.