# How can I get all referenced assemblies of a .NET dll/exe?

Tags: c#, reference

I found various questions (and answers) on this topic but they all end with 'use `GetReferencedAssemblies()` which doesn't return all assemblies but only some (I'm not sure how that method decides which assemblies to return. In an answer on SO it was claimed that unused references wouldn't be returned but I've at least two assemblies that reference (and use types/methods from) other assemblies that are not returned when calling `GetReferencedAssemblies`.

Specifically the assemblies not being returned are the ModelViews of two View projects. Both are only appearing in XAML code (DataContext) but they are being used/referenced and objects are being used to display stuff.

For the moment I'm thinking about writing a method that just crawls through the .csproj files to get the needed references but maybe someone has a better idea/knows what is going on with `GetReferencedAssemblies`.

**There are some questions about this already on SO, but none of them ever seemed to have a problem with used references not being returned.**

Please also note that this is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433973/getreferencedassemblies-doesnt-return-all-assemblies).

Comment: You could try the `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` method.

Comment: If the assemblies end up being loaded dynamically then you need to find all the places they can be named or referred to. GetReferencedAssemblies will only return those assemblies that were added as references to the project, it will not return assemblies that are referenced through strings or xaml or similar.

Comment: @thehennyy thought about it. I'd have to spin up one AppDomain/assembly to make sure that I only have the references of that assembly. That'd be possible, I guess. Not sure if all references are loaded when you load an assembly, IIRC some things can be lazy loaded

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen good point but the references in question are referenced in the .csproj file. They're not loaded by MEF or reflection.