# How do I reference an assembly with no public types?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly, mef

I am writing an application that uses some setup code for establishing a database connection and various context settings. I do not have access to the sources of that setup code.

Among many other things, that setup code uses MEF to instantiate a certain class that implements a public interface. An exception will be thrown if no such class is found.

Unfortunately, the only class *C* that implements that interface is an `internal` class in an assembly *A*. Assembly *A* contains no public types whatsoever (and whose sources I cannot access, either). However, only assemblies whose contents are used get loaded by the CLR, and, while I could trigger the loading with `Assembly.Load`, I can only get the referenced assembly name from `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` if some use of the assembly is actually recognized by the compiler - [otherwise, the reference will be optimized away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433973/getreferencedassemblies-doesnt-return-all-assemblies).

At runtime, I do not know the physical location of *A*, which makes dynamical loading by file name problematic. I might be able to *guess* it by looking at the location of certain other assemblies, but that seems quite hacky to me.

Furthermore, I cannot implement the interface myself (or rather, it would make no sense to do so), as I do not have the information that must be returned by some of the interface's methods. (In fact, as I do not have any documentation for the interface, I am not even sure what the interface members are supposed to do or return in some cases.)

**What options do I have to make sure *C* is around when the setup code attempts to retrieve the interface implementation?**

Comment: Appeal to the authors of the assembly to make it more useful?

Comment: @JonSkeet: No chance, unfortunately. The core components work in the complete deployable application that gets delivered to customers. No-one will (dare to) change them for the sole purpose of accessing things in tools that are only useful to the developers (which is what I have to work on).

Comment: You say an exception is thrown if C (which implements an interface) is not found. That 3rd party assembly, who is looking for the class, by which rules does it play? Is it a publicly known assembly? Does it only scan loaded assemblies? Or does it also scan all assemblies in the bin-folder? Do you have bin-folder? Is a reference required? Why not include the assembly `A` as a resource and copy it to the bin-folder using the "Copy Always" setting?

Comment: @MartinMulder: Internally, it uses `GetExportedValue<...>()` from MEF, with `...` being the interface. I do not "have" assembly *A*. It is supplied from a repository based upon our nightly build. From there, it gets into something like a large *bin*  folder, yes - but, as I said, I am not sure where that folder is located at runtime, and "guessing" its location (let alone hard-coding it) feels hacky.

Comment: Base upon your situation, you say you cannot reference party because it does not contain public types. But suppose it would have contained public types, how would you have solved your problem since you do not "have" `A`?

Comment: @MartinMulder: I would add a reference from within the IDE (VS in this case). We are using an addin that uses an MSBuild variable to indicate the path to referenced assemblies from our product. Things will be built the correct way by some "magic" that happens deep down in the build tooling. (We're talking about a bigger project here, > 50 solutions with ~10 projects each.)

Comment: Is it possibly to reproduce that "magic", that "variable" which will resolve that actual path?

Comment: @MartinMulder: Well ... if the application can access its `.csproj` file and the underlying variables such as `$(SolutionDir)` at runtime, there might be a chance. But I do not think that data is (read: should be) available at runtime.

Comment: If the information is stored in the csproj-file, which location is that? And who put that information there? And is there a relation between that location and the location of the project itself (parent folder, child folder, etc.)? (Sorry, for all the questions, perhaps I am missing something, but I suspect the deeper we go, the closer we get...)

Comment: @MartinMulder: It's a relative path based upon the solution location, supplied by the people who manage the builds. Of course, I can *copy* that path, but when the people who manage the build configuration decide to revamp the folder structure again, my code would break. At the same time, maybe understandably, those build managers cannot be bothered to add any exceptions or special scripts for various dozens of internal tools that developers build. Unfortunately, I am confronted with a general unwillingness to spend any effort unless it is directly for code that ends up in end-user products.

Comment: So... If you would have made a reference to that file, that files would have been copied to the bin folder and it will become part of the build/release, right? Or will the refered DLL not be part of the build/release? If is will become part of the build, why not make a reference like you make references to other files like images, a text file, whatever? And mark it as "Copy Always" so it will always be copied to the bin-folder, making it part of the build/release?

Comment: @MartinMulder: Well, I'm not sure what will happen to the reference settings, both due to the aforementioned addins that originally create the reference, and with respect to possible bulk edits across all projects in the repo when something about the build tooling or similar changes. Basically, the only thing I feel confident to rely on is whether or not the project has a reference to a given assembly at design time. Still, that seems like a worthwhile idea for now, as my tool will have to be changed anyway (e.g. AppDomain ref paths) if the location of dependent assemblies changes, I guess.