# Getting all the assemblies in a package in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to retrieve a list with **all the `Assemblies` in an application package** in order to load them dynamically.

I'm trying with this code:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Assembly> AssembliesInAppFolder
        {
            get
            {
                var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                var path = entryAssembly.Location;
                var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                var assemblies = new Collection<Assembly>();

                var fileNames = FilterFiles(folder, ".dll", ".exe");

                foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(fileName));
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException)
                    {
                    }
                    catch (FileLoadException)
                    {
                    }
                    catch (BadImageFormatException)
                    {
                    }
                }

                return assemblies;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> FilterFiles(string path, params string[] extensionsWithNoWildcard)
        {
            return
                Directory
                    .EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*")
                    .Where(file => extensionsWithNoWildcard.Any(x => file.EndsWith(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
        }
```

But it doesn't work in Android (in Release mode, it throws at `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*")` - where path is an empty string saying this:

"System.ArgumentException: The specified path is not of a legal form (empty)."

[image: Snapshot of the Exception]

Comment: i faced this issue once too and resorted to using Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies instead to get shipped assemblies

Comment: Fair enough! However, getting the reference assemblies that way doesn't get all of them that are actually referenced. It seems similar to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433973/getreferencedassemblies-doesnt-return-all-assemblies

Comment: you get pretty close if you're doing it for all resolved referenced assemblies too (recursively or however). in some cases where your code only relies on assemblies through reflection you might have to add a code reference to a type in the assembly that couldn't be resolved. like they say: the compiler tends to remove the reference