# C# Prevent Compiler from Trimming unused References

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-assembly, csproj

As per here: [GetReferencedAssemblies doesn't return all assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433973/getreferencedassemblies-doesnt-return-all-assemblies), the C# compiler will remove any project references which it judges to be unused. I've confirmed this is still the case - examining the compiled dll shows that it has no reference to the "Referenced-but-unused" project.

The simplest 'hack' is create a dummy usage of the referenced project.
But **is there a better way to tell the Compiler that it shouldn't discard the "unused" references?**
Either for some specific project dependency, or just tell it not to do that at all.

Comments on the linked question seem to suggest not, but since that wasn't the primary subject of the question (and it was also asked > 10 years ago!) I'm hoping that there are new solutions to the problem.

---

*Since people will no-doubt ask, I'm doing some reflection-y, attribute-tagged inferred associations work. Yes, it's ugly.*

Comment: *I'm doing some reflection-y, attribute-tagged inferred associations work.* then do not add references ... use `Assembly.Load`

Comment: @Selvin how would I know what Assemblies to Load?

Comment: from some config file? or from subfolder

Comment: If `ProjectA` has a csproj reference to `ProjectB`, but the compiler judges that the reference is unused ... how does my reflection code find out that `ProjectB` exists, and where the dll is located?

Comment: ProjectA output would be fx `/bin/` then ProjectB would be `/bin/assembliestoload` .. now ProjectA should load all dll from `assembliestoload` ... it's rather problem of deploying not compiling

Comment: I thought there was a setting in the project properties/app tab/assembly information button of "remove unused (something)".. but I'll just check.. Edit: eh, nope. Either I'm going crazy or it's no longer a thing

Comment: @CaiusJard yeah, I was really hoping that exactly that sort of setting had been introduced since the linked Question :D