# Is `GetReferencedAssemblies` a subset of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`?

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, assembly-loading

I want to test some reflection code I've written.

There's an edge case that would occur if the ReferencedAssemblies were ever not already loaded into the AppDomain, i.e. if the following expression ever returned `true`:

```
typeof(MyType).Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
    .Except(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(assem => assem.GetName()))
    .Any()
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Can that ever return `true`? (I think "yes" [and hence the answer to the headline question is "no"], though I'm not certain).
2. Assuming it can ... then how can I orchestrate that, for the purposes of a unit test?

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, it is NOT a subset.

You CAN have a situation in which a `ReferencedAssembly` has not currently been loaded into the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`.

To achieve this in a test:

1. Create a secondary `csproj`. (`ProjTwo`)
2. Create a `csproj`-level dependency between your Test project and `ProjTwo`.
3. Add an unused class that references some code in `ProjTwo`.

   - If necessary add a static class with a static no-op method to `ProjTwo`, and a second static class which just invokes that method to your Test proj.
4. Do NOT reference `ProjTwo` assembly anywhere in your TestFixtures.

Voila!

---

Step 4. appears to mean that `ProjTwo` does not get Loaded, whilst Step 3. ensures that the compiler can't remove the reference so it still turns up in `GetReferencedAssemblies()`, dodging [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433973/getreferencedassemblies-doesnt-return-all-assemblies).

Comment: On the other hand, a plugin system (MEF or otherwise) can load assemblies that aren't referenced. So it all depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, sometimes you need either of those, other times you want both.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm slightly struggling to parse your comment :D Are you trying to point out that (in addition to my above observation that you can have a situation in which an `Assembly` is referenced but not loaded) you can also have a situation in which an `Assembly` is loaded but not referenced by any other loaded Assembly. (e.g. by invoking `Assembly.Load()` or similar)

Comment: And that sometimes you care about your target being in one collection, other times being in the other collection, and other times you'd need it to be in both of those collections.

Comment: If so, I agree! But if you meant something else, could you expand so that I can understand your point? :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. If you want to analyze all loaded assemblies which may or may not be referenced (plugin example), you need a different API than when you want to analyze referenced assemblies. That's what I mean by "Sometimes you want either, other times you want both".