# How to get types which implements specific interface from referenced NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nuget

I'm trying to find a way to get all classes which implement some interface where the location of these classes are in referenced NuGet packages.

I know how to do it with referenced dll files by using `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`.
But how can I explore NuGet packages?
Is there some nuget which can help with this task?

I tried to look at the PackageManager class but I didn't find what I wanted.

Comment: Nuget packages are a compile-time construct. At Runtime, you just have normal assembly references, so `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` will continue to work.

Comment: Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies function doesn't return DLL of my NuGet package. I need to provide the name of the DLL through config file and after that I'm using Assembly.Load method to get an assembly. Currently this is my solution. Because after all the dll file indeed exists in the runtime directory after compilation BUT it is missing in the array which returns by Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies function. @KlausGütter

Comment: The compiler will indeed remove references that are not actually used. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433973/getreferencedassemblies-doesnt-return-all-assemblies

Comment: If your aim is something like a plugin architecture, maybe [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) would be a way to go.

Comment: I will read about MEF. Also I need to check if it is a first time when i try to access this assembly and may be this is the reason why i don't get assembly name when i call GetReferencedAssemblies . Thank you for helping me. @KlausGütter

Comment: If all this is 100% dynamic, task is much harder. Perhaps show some code.

Answer (score 0):

As Klaus says in the comments, at runtime you're still dealing with assemblies. So you can use the technique you are currently using.

To avoid scanning every assembly, you can pick a type in the target assembly (NuGet package), get its `Assembly` property, and load types from that.

```cs
typeof(SomeTypeInSomeNuGetPackageAssembly).Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.GetInterface("...") != null)
    ...
```

Comment: Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies function doesn't return DLL of my NuGet package. I need to provide the name of the DLL through config file and after that I'm using Assembly.Load method to get an assembly. Currently this is my solution. Because after all the dll file indeed exists in the runtime directory after compilation BUT it is missing in the array which returns by Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies function.

Comment: If you use my approach of picking any public type in each of your target dependent NuGet packages and using its `Assembly` property to `GetTypes()` with your filter for implementation of matching interfaces, you will not need to call `Assembly.Load` nor will you have to attempt to iterate through referenced assemblies.

Comment: There are times when `GetReferencedAssemblies` does not return what you expect, because assemblies are typically loaded just in time. If you haven't yet accessed anything in your NuGet package, that's probaly why you're not getting back its assembly. My method gets past that because it forces a reference through a hard access to one of the types... `typeof(SomethingInNuGet).Assembly....`.

Comment: it was exactly my solution to use SomethingInNuGet type to get it's assembly and scan it. But the input was changed (it's a third party) and now i don't know ahead what will be this type. I just know the interface and i need to find out what classes implement this interface. I need to check if it is a first time to access this assembly and may be this is the reason why i don't get assembly name when i call GetReferencedAssemblies . Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Logically if you are referencing a NuGet package you would know of at least one public type in said NuGet package. If this wasn't the case, wouldn't the NuGet package be useless to others? I'm a bit confused. Unless someone was "abusing the system" and publishing a package *only* meant for dynamic loading...

Comment: u r right. i need it for some kind of dynamic loading. the nuget package will be created by third party. after that my csproj will be updated with this nuget and the CI/CD process will compile everything and bring all the application in the docker file

Comment: Well, not a solution to your immediate problem, but you say "the nuget package will be created". If you have any sway over the decision, have them embed some well known type in their assembly that you can reference, then you can go from there by referencing that type at startup -- forcing the NuGet's assembly to be loaded into the same context up front, then the reflection would work.